# Non-numeric argument to binary operator in R

Tags: r, string, integer, rstudio

I'm trying to plot some numbers in a graph, in the line x and y. The problem is I'm formatting the numbers as 3M for 3.000.000, 10k for 10.000, then I'm trying to put these numbers in the graph using the `axis` function, the problem is that I'm getting the message "Non-numeric argument to binary operator"

```css
x<-c(10000,20000,50000,200000)
y<-c(24679826,99532203,623224134,1422415645)
x1<-paste(format(round(x / 1e3, 1), trim = TRUE), "K")
y1<-c(paste(format(round(y / 1e6, 1), trim = TRUE), "M"))

options(scipen=999)
plot(planilha2$N,planilha2$Iteracoes_Insercao,type="b",
       xlab="Tamanho dos Vetores",
       ylab="Numero de iterações",
       xaxt="n",yaxt="n",pch=16,col="red",lwd=2.2,
       main="Inserção iterativo (Vetores gerados aleatoriamente)", 
       cex.main=1)

axis(1, (paste(format(round(x1 / 1e3, 1), trim = TRUE), "K")))
axis(2,paste(round(y / 1e6, 1), trim = TRUE), "M")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTRwj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to address here:

First, the error you're receiving is telling you this: You are applying some function, which requires a numeric value, to a value that is not numeric. In this case it is: `x1/ 1e3`. x1 is set a few lines earlier to a character vector. It is a group of character strings, so you cannot divide it by `1e3`. I am assuming this is a typo, and you meant `x` instead of `x1`.

Next, you are missing some arguments to the `axis()` function. You need to tell `axis()` which points to draw the labels *and* what labels to draw. See the documentation for the `axis()` function.

To help you out, I fixed the code so that it draws a plot here:

```
x<-c(10000,20000,50000,200000)
y<-c(24679826,99532203,623224134,1422415645)

options(scipen=999)
plot(x, y,type="b",
     xlab="Tamanho dos Vetores",
     ylab="Numero de iterações",
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n",pch=16,col="red",lwd=2.2,
     main="Inserção iterativo (Vetores gerados aleatoriamente)", 
     cex.main=1)

axis(1, x,  labels = paste(format(round(x / 1e3, 1), trim = TRUE), "K"))
axis(2, y, labels = paste(format(round(y / 1e6, 1), trim = TRUE), "M"))
```

But, you will probably need to do some reading/experimentation to understand *why* I made the changes I did. For example, in your code you gave example vectors `x` and `y`, but then plotted columns from the data frame `planilha2`. Can you see why I had to change the `plot()` function in order for your example to run?

Comment: I'm workingin  r since today and i'm getting lost sometimes haha, I was calling plotting columns of a data frame because my teacher was showing me the difference between calling from a csv and putting as a variable. Thanks for the help, but i'm still having the message for the axis with the y